# How to tell if the point is in the ellipse

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I want to know if the `pt` is in the ellipse

The ellipse property is like this below.

```
center = [10,10]
radius = [3,4]//vertical radius and holizontal radius.
```

I can get the length from `center` to `pt`

```
var length_from_center = Math.sqrt((center[0] - pt[0]) ** 2 + (center[1] - pt[1]) ** 2);
```

If circle, I can check the `pt` is in circle easily.

However this is ellipse, how can I check the `pt` is in ellipse?

Comment: On a technical note, an ellipse also needs an angle, even if it's 0, since it's not radially symmetrical like a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of your ellipse is

```
(x-10)² / 4² + (y-10)² / 3² <= 1
```

Calculate `(x-10)² / 4² + (y-10)² / 3²` for your point `(x,y)` and compare to `1`.

Comment: Thank you it works for my purpose. I need to learn Math more....